# Is there a different way that I could display my tables based on my arguments entered using the argparse module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, argparse

The goal is to display tables based on arguments entered in the terminal.

I've tried to create a function that would output each individual table using if, elif and else statements but that would only display the tables individually.

I've also tried a different way which is preferred and it would add a column to my table based on my arguments.

```
def generate_table(inventory):
    args = arguments()
    data = generate_data(inventory)

    main_headers = ['os_version', 'serial_number']
    lldp_headers = ['lldp']
    out_file = ['outfile']
    main_header = []
    lldp_header = []
    main_table_header = PrettyTable()
    lldp_table_header = PrettyTable()

    for arg in vars(args):
        if arg in main_headers and getattr(args, arg):
            main_header.append(arg)
        elif arg in lldp_headers and getattr(args, arg):
            lldp_header.append(arg)
        elif arg in out_file and getattr(args, arg):
            out_file.append(arg)
            output_file(inventory)

    main_header.insert(0, 'Hostname')
    main_table_header.field_names = main_header
    lldp_table_header.field_names = ['Hostname', 'Neighbor', 'Local Interface', 'Neighbor Interface']

    for hostname, details in data.items():
        row = [hostname]
        for column in main_table_header.field_names[1:]:
            row.append(details[column])
        main_table_header.add_row(row)
        for lldp_data in details['lldp']:
            neighbor = lldp_data['device-id']
            local_int = lldp_data['local-interface']
            neigh_int = lldp_data['connecting-interface']
        lldp_table_header.add_row([hostname, neighbor, local_int, neigh_int])


    print(main_table_header)
    print(lldp_table_header)




def arguments():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Argparse for Training Course.')
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--serial_number', action='store_true', help='Device Serial Numbers')
    parser.add_argument('-v', '--os_version', action='store_true', help='Output Devices OS')
    parser.add_argument('--lldp', action='store_true', help='Output LLDP Data')
    parser.add_argument('--outfile', action='store_true', help='Output to file')
    parser.add_argument('--inventory', help='Inventory File', default=["inventory.yml"], required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    return args


def get_inventory(inventory):
    with open(inventory) as fh:
        yml_file = yaml.load(fh)

    return yml_file


def main():
    args = arguments()
    if not os.path.isfile(args.inventory):
        sys.exit('Please specify valid, readable YAML file with data')

    inventory = get_inventory(args.inventory)
    generate_table(inventory)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
YAML FILE:

csr1:
  username: admin
  password: pass
  transport: restconf
csr2:
  username: admin
  password: pass
  transport: restconf
```

This is what I expect:

```
python3 rest5.py --inventory inventory.yml -v
+----------+------------+
| Hostname | os_version |
+----------+------------+
| csr1     |    16.6    |
| csr2     |    16.6    |
+----------+------------+

python3 rest5.py --inventory inventory.yml -s
+----------+---------------+
| Hostname | serial_number |
+----------+---------------+
| csr1     |  9KIBQAQ3OPE  |
| csr2     |  9KIBQAQ3OPE  |
+----------+---------------+

python3 rest5.py --inventory inventory.yml -s -v
+----------+---------------+------------+
| Hostname | serial_number | os_version |
+----------+---------------+------------+
| csr1     |  9KIBQAQ3OPE  |    16.6    |
| csr2     |  9KIBQAQ3OPE  |    16.6    |
+----------+---------------+------------+
python3 rest5.py --inventory inventory.yml --lldp
+----------+--------------+-----------------+--------------------+
| Hostname |   Neighbor   | Local Interface | Neighbor Interface |
+----------+--------------+-----------------+--------------------+
| csr1     | csr2.com     |       Gi1       |        Gi1         |
| csr2     | csr1.com     |       Gi1       |        Gi1         |
+----------+--------------+-----------------+--------------------+
python3 rest5.py --inventory inventory.yml --lldp -s -v
+----------+---------------+------------+
| Hostname | serial_number | os_version |
+----------+---------------+------------+
| csr1     |  9KIBQAQ3OPE  |    16.6    |
| csr2     |  9KIBQAQ3OPE  |    16.6    |
+----------+---------------+------------+
+----------+--------------+-----------------+--------------------+
| Hostname |   Neighbor   | Local Interface | Neighbor Interface |
+----------+--------------+-----------------+--------------------+
| csr1     | csr2.com     |       Gi1       |        Gi1         |
| csr2     | csr1.com     |       Gi1       |        Gi1         |
+----------+--------------+-----------------+--------------------+
```

The actual output:

```
python3 rest5.py --inventory inventory.yml -s
+----------+---------------+
| Hostname | serial_number |
+----------+---------------+
| csr1     |  9KIBQAQ3OPE  |
| csr2     |  9KIBQAQ3OPE  |
+----------+---------------+
+----------+--------------+-----------------+--------------------+
| Hostname |   Neighbor   | Local Interface | Neighbor Interface |
+----------+--------------+-----------------+--------------------+
| csr1     | csr2.com     |       Gi1       |        Gi1         |
| csr2     | csr1.com     |       Gi1       |        Gi1         |
+----------+--------------+-----------------+--------------------+

python3 rest5.py --inventory inventory.yml --lldp
+----------+
| Hostname |
+----------+
| csr1     |
| csr2     |
+----------+
+----------+--------------+-----------------+--------------------+
| Hostname |   Neighbor   | Local Interface | Neighbor Interface |
+----------+--------------+-----------------+--------------------+
| csr1     | csr2.com     |       Gi1       |        Gi1         |
| csr2     | csr1.com     |       Gi1       |        Gi1         |
+----------+--------------+-----------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: hey there, please try to have a [`mcve`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Try passing in `args` to your `generate_table` function and remove the `args = arguments()` in the  `generate_table` function. So then you can call it like  `generate_table(inventory, args)`. 

Also you can remove `args = arguments()` from your `output_file` function.

Comment: Usually code like your `arguments` function is run once via the `__main__` block, and the result, either as an `args` Namespace, or individual variables, is passed to functions.  That way, the functions can be imported and used without ever running `argparse` (or otherwise using `sys.argv`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `generate_table` method is always printing out two tables, when you only want it to print out one:

Your original function:

```
def generate_table(inventory):
    args = arguments()
    ... 

    print(main_table_header)
    print(lldp_table_header)
```

Should simply change to:

```
def generate_table(inventory):
    args = arguments()
    ... 

    if args.lldp:
        print(lldp_table_header)
    else:
        print(main_table_header)
```

Other commenters mentioned optimizations that would generally make the code better which you should consider implementing, such as:

- only generating `arguments` once
- create only the tables you're going to render instead of running through the motions of creating tables that you aren't going to print in the end

But at the end of the day, you were just a few lines away from making your use cases stated above work the way you wanted them to.

Comment: Thanks for tips, it helped.. I ended up adding a few more lines from what you showed.

```
    if args.os_version and args.lldp and args.serial_number:
        print(lldp_table_header)
        print(main_table_header)
    elif args.lldp:
        print(lldp_table_header)
    elif args.os_version:
        print(main_table_header)
    elif args.serial_number:
        print(main_table_header)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
    args = arguments()
    if not os.path.isfile(args.inventory):
        sys.exit('Please specify valid, readable YAML file with data')

    inventory = get_inventory(args.inventory)
    generate_table(inventory, args)
```

You call `get_inventory` with a string, a values from `args`.  You should also call `generate_table` with values from `args`, or `args` itself.  Reevaluating `args` works, but just makes your code messier.

```
def generate_table(inventory, args):
    # args = arguments()    # no need to reevaluate args
    data = generate_data(inventory)
    ...
```

Same could be done for `output_file`, though it isn't obvious where  you are using `args`.

In `generate_table` you appear to use `args` mainly in:

```
for arg in vars(args):
    if arg in main_headers and getattr(args, arg):
        main_header.append(arg)
    elif arg in lldp_headers and getattr(args, arg):
        lldp_header.append(arg)
    elif arg in out_file and getattr(args, arg):
        out_file.append(arg)
        output_file(inventory)
```

That's an obscure piece of code, treating `args` both as Namespace and dictionary.  I think it's just checking on the values of

```
args.os_version
args.serial_number
args.lldp
args.outfile
```

Those are all `store_true`, so they will always be present, and a `True/False` value.  So you could

```
if args.out_file:
    output_file(inventory)

if args.lldp:
    lldp_header.append('lldp')
```

But I'm not too interested in digging through all the logic steps.

Make sure that you understand what `parse_args` has produced.  During debugging I encourage users to

```
 print(args)
```

That way there'll be fewer surprises.

Comment: Yes the idea is to check what arguments are being triggered by the user and get appended to my headers list so it can be reused to add the table header dynamically and also add a new row based on that argument.